# Visual Studio 2013 OpenCL header file not found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, opencl, cl

Recently I installed OpenCL to practice OpenCL and I tried to run some sample code, but it shows two errors.

1. > error CL: 'stdio.h' file not found
2. > error MSB3721: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.3\bin\x86\ioc32.exe" -cmd=build -input="c:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenCLtest\OpenCLtest\test.cl" -output="Debug\test.out" -VS -device=GPU -simd=default -targetos=current            -bo="           "" (code: -1).    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\IntelOpenCL.targets  98  5   OpenCLtest

Comment: Is `stdio.h` includable in new created projects?

Comment: can you please add the sample code you tried to run

Comment: What I want to do is just simple matrix multiplication..